# Autocomplete, load records on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5. I have an autocomplete and I want on search to load 20 rows, when the user scrols to the bottom to load more 10 results (if any). This is my autocomplete:

```
<p:autoComplete rendered="#{autoCompleter.hasCompletions}" widgetVar="${id}"
        id="${id}" style="position: relative"
        value="#{autoCompleter.value}"
        completeMethod="#{autoCompleter.suggest}" 
        var="s"
        itemLabel="#{s.name}" 
        itemValue="#{s}"
        converter="#{autoCompleter.converter}" 
        forceSelection="true"
        queryDelay="500"
        scrollHeight="400"
        required="#{required}"
        requiredMessage="#{msgs['label.address.autocompleter.required']}"
        styleClass="#{required ? 'ui-input-required' : ''}"
        maxResults="#{autoCompleter.maxResult}">

        <p:ajax event="change"
                partialSubmit="true"
                update="#{update}"  
                onstart="if(${id}.panel.is(':visible')) return false;"/>

        <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                partialSubmit="true"
                update="#{update}"/>

        <p:ajax event="blur"
                partialSubmit="true"
                update="#{update}"
                disabled="true"/>

        <ui:insert name="menu">
            <p:column>#{s.name}</p:column>
        </ui:insert>

    </p:autoComplete>
```

And I have added this javascript to do the loading of the next result chunks:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="loadNextSettlementsChunk"
                 action="#{autoCompleter.suggest}"
                 update="${id}"     
                 partialSubmit="true"
                 immediate="true"/>
```

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete-panel').bind('scroll', function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                loadNextSettlementsChunk();
            }   
        });
    });
</script>
```

But instead of loading the next results I'm getting warning message:

> **Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id
>   '/policies/index.xhtml' for action '#{autoCompleter.suggest}' with
>   outcome '[Văleni (Viișoara), Viișoara, Viișoara (Todirești), Viișoara
>   (Vaslui), Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara,
>   Viișoara-Moșneni, Viișoara, Viișoara Mică, Viișoara (Păunești),
>   Viișoara (Vidra), Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara, Viișoara
>   (Ștefan cel Mare), Viișoara (Târgu Trotuș), Viișoara, Viișoara,
>   Viilor, Valea Viilor, Dealu Viilor, Dealu Viilor (Moșoaia), Dealu
>   Viilor (Poiana Lacului)]'** and in the [] brackets are my results. How
>   to fix this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

The `action` attribute must point to a method which invokes some business logic and returns either **void** or a **String**, but the result of your method `suggest` is an **ArrayList**. Therefore, I suggest you to use `actionListener` instead of `action`in order to invokes your business logic without navigation page.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="loadNextSettlementsChunk"
                 actionListener="#{autoCompleter.suggest}"
                 update="${id}"     
                 partialSubmit="true"
                 immediate="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried this two, but it doesn't work. Only the warning message doesn't show up. If I pass ${id} to update attribute of remoteCommand it selects the last entry in the autocomplete input field.